# How does podman run amd64 OS on apple silicon

Tags: vm, podman

I use podman to build some `x86_64` executables on `m1` mac for a while, and I know it uses qemu to run machine, that provides backend that "hosts" containers.
Recently I was very surprised, that it runs:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 ... -accel hvf -accel tcg -cpu host -M virt,highmem=on ... podman-machine-default_fedora-coreos-38.20231002.2.2-qemu.aarch64.qcow2 ...
```

I've ommitted part of command, that's not related to question. So, it's not an `qemu-system-x86_64` emulator, nor `fedora-whatever.x86_64.qcow2` image.

Inside the container i see:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 601bbcda527a 6.5.5-200.fc38.aarch64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Sep 24 16:14:15 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I'm able to build and run amd64 executables.

---

The reason, I ask is because this builder instance is pretty performant, but now I'm trying to run bare `qemu-system-x86_64` emulated virtual machine, without podman and find it to be much much slower. It uses only `-accel tcg`, because `-accel hvf` is not available.

---

Actual question is, can someone overview mechanisms used by podman to provide auch a performant way to run amd64 stuff and is there a chance to acheive comparable performance, using only qemu, without podman (I mean simple way, not involving to develop podman or docker like software).

Comment: I'm almost sure now, that it performs something similar to what is described here: https://docs.getutm.app/advanced/rosetta/

Comment: PR for adding Rosetta support to Podman: https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/21670 The PR has not yet been merged as of today (2024 February 18)